# SQL displaying the specific column

Tags: sql, oracle

How should I write a query that only shows the inside column values with "YES" ?

```
Hospital_ID  MATERINITY  ENT  DERMATOLOGY  ORTHOPEDICS  
          1  YES         NO   NO           NO   
          2  YES         YES  NO           NO   
          3  YES         YES  NO           YES
```

The result I'm looking for is Hospital_ID "3":

```
Hospital_ID  MATERINITY  ENT  ORTHOPEDICS  
          3  YES         YES  YES
```

that won't show the column with value "NO".

Comment: I cannot see the imagur.com content. What is your current query? Please post the statement that starts "SELECT ...". DDL for the table(s) might also be helpful.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: If you want to exclude columns you must do it in your client, there's no SQL syntax to filter columns.

Comment: Are you trying to exclude the entire dermatology column because all of its values are No; or all rows that have any of the other three columns set to No; or both; or something else?

Comment: yea i only need exclude the dermatology column when the values is NO. Not because all row of dermatology is NO.

Comment: So why is there only one row? Anyway, you can't exclude a column from the result set like that without dynamic SQL; the select list (i.e. columns) needs to be known when the query is parsed. You could get a single column result, as CSV, but then how would you interpret it?

Comment: If I remember correctly from the other question you asked here in the last day or two, this is for your own learning. Creating results with a variable number of columns depending on conditions is an advanced topic - you can ONLY do that with "dynamic SQL." On the other hand, if this for REPORTING purposes only, use the right tools - namely, reporting tools. If you are still just learning SQL and Oracle basics, what you are asking in this question is too ambitious. (Note also that "proper database design" with a table for specialties would help! but still dynamic SQL required...)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName 
WHERE MATERINITY = "YES" AND 
      DERMATOLOGY = "YES" AND 
      ORTHOPEDICS = "YES"
```

Comment: `MATERINITY = "YES"` will not work. `"YES"` is an identifier (e.g. a column name). Strings need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL: `'YES'`

Comment: This also won't exclude the dermatology column. If that is what the OP really wants.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're only looking to exclude the dermatology column when it's NO and you don't care about any of the other columns being NO (unless they're all NO) then it would be:

```
SELECT Hospital_ID, MATERNITY, ENT, ORTHOPEDICS,
FROM DepartmentTable
WHERE DERMATOLOGY = 'NO' AND (MATERNITY = 'YES' OR ENT = 'YES' OR ORTHOPEDICS = 'YES');
```

This would only give you the rows where DERMATOLOGY is NO but there is another column with a 'YES' value.  I'm assuming you don't want results where all columns are 'NO'.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to get into trouble trying to drop columns, especially when you include multiple hospitals.  I would recommend doing the yesses as rows with a union query, then you can crosstab in your report.

```
SELECT Hospital_ID, 'MATERNITY' Dept FROM myTable t WHERE t.MATERNITY='YES'
UNION SELECT Hospital_ID, 'ENT' Dept FROM myTable t WHERE t.ENT='YES'
UNION SELECT Hospital_ID, 'DERMATOLOGY' Dept FROM myTable t WHERE t.DERMATOLOGY='YES'
UNION SELECT Hospital_ID, 'ORTHOPEDICS' Dept FROM myTable t WHERE t.ORTHOPEDICS='YES'
```

If you need to filter for hospital id = 3 then do:

```
SELECT Hospital_ID, Dept FROM (
SELECT Hospital_ID, 'MATERNITY' Dept FROM myTable t WHERE t.MATERNITY='YES'
UNION SELECT Hospital_ID, 'ENT' Dept FROM myTable t WHERE t.ENT='YES'
UNION SELECT Hospital_ID, 'DERMATOLOGY' Dept FROM myTable t WHERE t.DERMATOLOGY='YES'
UNION SELECT Hospital_ID, 'ORTHOPEDICS' Dept FROM myTable t WHERE t.ORTHOPEDICS='YES') x
WHERE Hospital_ID=3
```